# is there a list of websites which have rest api

Tags: android, rest

I want to develop some application for android, but struggled to decide what it should do :)

Is there a collection/list of web-sites which have REST api? So I can implement in in my app
and make use of it?

thanks!

Comment: did u google? u r looking for webservice right?

Comment: of course i did, it only gives some specific api s, im wondering if there is a collection/list? :)  yes, for some list of webservices

Comment: oh ok , i m familiar with php webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at http://www.programmableweb.com/apis. I'm sure there others out there as well, but that's what I'm familiar with.